# PHP email render issue

Tags: php, email

I send HTML email, everything is ok except that it adds the tag `<br>` after each tag.

Before sending

```
<div>Content 1</div>
<img src="http://mylink.com/img.png" />
<div>Content 2</div>
```

After sending

```
<div>Content 1</div>
<br>
<img src="http://mylink.com/img.png" />
<br>
<div>Content 2</div>
<br>
```

Whats the wrong? why it is adding the br tag????

Comment: What editor you are using to write the code?

Comment: looks like output is being put through nl2br() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd need to see more code to help, but it looks like you are using a RTE/WYSIWYG editor which automatically converts `\n` (newlines) into `<br>` to try and be helpful.  Or, you are passing the email body through a formatting function that will format the text in a way like this.

Comment: No, neither i am using RTE nor passing through any function it is just hard coded things.

Comment: i m using osCommerce tep_mail() function